# Nested <form> linking to another .html file

Tags: html, forms

Very new to html. I'm trying to create a "log in" page that has a button that links to another "sign up" html page. But I run into a problem, as I want my 3 buttons (log in, reset, sign up) to be on the same line. 
The main form will link to the main website once logged in, while the "sign up" form button is supposed to send me to the sign-up.html page. If I make the forms separate, the "sign up" button will be in a new line, but if I make them nested, it will require me to fill the form. 
Thanks!

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <b> Email </b>
        <input type="Email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="Email" required="">
        <br><br>
        <b>Password: </b>
        <input type="Password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="Password" required="">
        <br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" unchecked="unchecked"> Remember me
        <br><br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Log in</button>
        <button type="Reset">Reset</button>
        <form action="sign up.html">
         <button>Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Your problem seems to be focused on styling with the buttons display. Are you familiar with CSS (cascading style sheets)? CSS will help you get your display to look the way you want it to. Also, find a website that is doing what you want to do and examine it with Chrome's "Inspect" to see how it was done.

Comment: @JohnH John, when editing questions and answers, you shouldn't correct syntax errors or the like, as it may change the scope of the question. Instead, you should mention it in a comment and let the OP fix it, so we know it's not interfering with the code they are actually using. I see now it may have been an accident, but your requested edit removed an element opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested forms are forbidden in HTML. You should use [a validator](https://validator.nu).

There is no need for the nested form to exist at all. You aren't collecting any data with it. Use a link instead. Apply CSS if you don't like the way it looks by default.